# Place text and buttons inside CSS grid

Tags: html, css

I am making a CSS grid, and have now tried to make some nested grids inside of an element.

The purpose of the nested grid is to have the possibility to make a text, and control where the text should be in the grid element. At the moment the text are in the top.

How can I make the text align fx in the center, or in the bottom of the grid element?

```css
.wrapper {
      display:grid;
      grid-template-columns:repeat(12,1fr);
      grid-gap: 10px;
      background-color: #fff;
      border: 10px solid #fff;
    } 
.nested {
      display:grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    }
    .nested > div {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    .item1 {
      grid-row: 1 / 3;
      grid-column: 1/7;
      height: 700px;
      background-color:blue;
    }
    .item2 {
      grid-row: 1 / 1;
      grid-column: 7/13;
      height: 340px;
      background-color:yellow;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item1">
        <div class="nested">
            <div>Lorem column 1</div>
            <div>Lorem column 1</div>
            <div>Lorem column 1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item2 bg-img">
        <div class="nested">
            <div>Lorem column 2</div>
            <div>Lorem column 2</div>
            <div>Lorem column 2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `justify-items: center` to the grid parent and it seems to have fixed the issue.

```css
.nested {
      display:grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
      justify-items: center;
    }
    .nested > div {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    .item1 {
      grid-row: 1 / 3;
      grid-column: 1/7;
      height: 700px;
      background-color:blue;
    }
    .item2 {
      grid-row: 1 / 1;
      grid-column: 7/13;
      height: 340px;
      background-color:yellow;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item1">
        <div class="nested">
            <div>Lorem column 1</div>
            <div>Lorem column 1</div>
            <div>Lorem column 1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item2 bg-img">
        <div class="nested">
            <div>Lorem column 2</div>
            <div>Lorem column 2</div>
            <div>Lorem column 2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But if I want the text in the middle of the blue grid element, and the text in the bottom of the yellow element. How am I gonna do this?

Comment: You'd probably be able to do that by changing `justify-content` and `align-content`. But is there more to this code. Like do u have styles set for `wrapper`? Cause over here it seems like `item1` and `item2` are grid elements. But that wouldn't work without setting `display: grid` for `wrapper`

Comment: Yes there is around 4000 lines of code :-) I just updated my wrapper class where the grid is defined. So the question is basically that I would like to have 100% control over where my text is placed in the grid element.

Comment: Why too much nesting!? :-) The whole thing looks so simple. Let's look at `item1` which is the blue one. there's a `grid` inside of it and u have to place that grid in the middle. So at this point it's not about css grid anymore. U r just trying to center a div vertically inside another div. Now u can make `item1` another grid to accomplish that. U can also use `flexbox` or absolute positioning.